# MySQL how to use `Load_file()` function with UNC path format?

Tags: mysql

I understand I need to use a specific path name as mentioned in documentation

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file

> To use this function, the file must be located on the server host

**Working path:**

This path here, whilst using function `load_file()`, currently saves as a blob attachment in MySQL database.

```
insert into document_control (fileattachment) values (load_file('C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\test.docx'))
```

**Non-working path**

This path does not work - even tho it's the same MySQL server folder on the PC is hosted on. The value shows as `Null`.

```
insert into document_control (fileattachment) values (load_file('\\winx-pc04\c$\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\test.docx'));
```

**Question**

Why does it not attach the file as a `BLOB`? Whilst it's still the correct server host path?

And how can I make it to work?

Comment: Your non-working path is in the [UNC path format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats#unc-paths) which  are used to access network resources, hence goes against the MySQL rule that the file must be located on the server host

Comment: @Jamie_D can I alter the server host path to any?

Comment: You should be able to load any file in the `C:\path\to\the\file` format

Comment: Im reading about secure_file_priv .. should that be disabled?

Comment: Basically, your script must have [file read privileges](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file) to the access you're trying to load. Not having used a Windows system in many years, it may be better if someone else shows you how to set that up ...;)

Comment: If, for example, you are building a database of images, I suggest you store the path, not the image, in the table.  This completely avoids the Question you have posed.

Comment: @RickJames reason I have avoided that is - if somebody deletes or moves some files?

Comment: There are pros and cons to the two approaches.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell briefly looking at [the source](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/item_strfunc.cc#L3480) on Windows, MySQL ends up calling [`CreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) and the only thing that stands between you and opening an UNC path is that  [`secure_file_priv`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv) setting:

> This variable is used to limit the effect of data import and export operations, such as those performed by the LOAD DATA and SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE statements and the LOAD_FILE() function. These operations are permitted only to users who have the FILE privilege.
>
> secure_file_priv may be set as follows:
>
> - If empty, the variable has no effect. This is not a secure setting.
> - If set to the name of a directory, the server limits import and export operations to work only with files in that directory. The directory must exist; the server will not create it.
> - If set to NULL, the server disables import and export operations.
>
> The server checks the value of secure_file_priv at startup and writes a warning to the error log if the value is insecure. A non-NULL value is considered insecure if it is empty, or the value is the data directory or a subdirectory of it, or a directory that is accessible by all users. If secure_file_priv is set to a nonexistent path, the server writes an error message to the error log and exits.

I am assuming you run Windows and have installed MySQL using their all-in-one msi installer. In this case the `secure_file_priv` was likely preconfigured for you to be
something like `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads`. Even though it is the same path, the [code seems to compare paths](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/mysqld.cc#L9997) as string values so your UNC path would still fail the check.

```sql
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%secure_file_priv%'
```

unfortunately, this setting cannot be updated dynamically, so you need to set it to an empty string via config and restart your server - it should work then. Note, however you might have to double up your slashes for the path to get escaped correctly:

```sql
insert into document_control (fileattachment) values (load_file('\\\\winx-pc04\\c$\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\test.docx'));
```

I haven't tested it, but potentially you can set the `secure_file_priv` to be your UNC path so the server does not throw any security warnings.

Anyway, here's an example of my working queries in MySQL Workbench (which might potentially be helpful)
[image: SELECT 'local', CONVERT(LOAD_FILE("D:\file.cs") USING utf8) UNION SELECT 'unc', CONVERT(LOAD_FILE("\\desktop-588s1o2\d$\file.cs") USING utf8);]

Comment: Another thing I did when playing with my server - I changed  the Windows service to run under my user account, not `NETWORK_SERVICE` - I was trying to eliminate account permissions level differences. Maybe that was it?

Comment: As experiment, maybe also try moving your folder out of program data (it's a bit of a special case isn't it) and allowing full access to `EVERYONE` onto that new location

Comment: Also wondering if you're using mysql workbench to test it out - I wonder if it's got some extra logic to make it work for me...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are going through an application language, such as PHP, have that load the image.  Then, I suggest you get the hex of the image, and unhex it in the sql:

```
INSERT INTO ... (..., image_blob, ...)
         VALUES ( ..., UNHEX(?), ...)
```

If the image is more than 500KB, you may need to increase a setting, since the single SQL statement will be more than 1MB.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but never got across to PHP. Python is probably my best bet.